# Facebook Auth sometimes returns OnCancel

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

My facebook auth in my app sometimes call the method onCancel, I don't know what's happening. I feel that my code is correct, sometimes the auth works very well, sometimes not.

The source code of my auth: https://gist.github.com/ppamorim/76d40f0edf3fd4f64d47

Then, this fail at line 46. Firstly I request this:

```
strings.add("public_profile");
strings.add("email");
loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(contextCallback.getActivity(), strings);
```

Then, I call this:

```
ArrayList<String> stringss = new ArrayList<>();
stringss.add("publish_actions");
loginManager.logInWithPublishPermissions(contextCallback.getActivity(), stringss);
```

The auth works fine there, but after the return to my app, this fall to OnCancel randomly.

Manifest:

```
<!-- Facebook Keys -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProviderHIDDEN_KEY"
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:exported="true" />
```

I don't know what's happening...

EDIT 1:

I changed the source but has the same problem:

https://gist.github.com/ppamorim/446183341ecd5ad099fe

EDIT 2:

New update, less code of course.
But still not working, it stops at line 53.
I'll remove the `publish_actions` right now, then when it has solved, I'll return with this feature.

https://gist.github.com/ppamorim/3cd0a141aac5d52bd60e

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can invoke the login dialog twice in short succession, like you are doing:

```
public Facebook authorize(/* ... */) {
    // ...
    ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    strings.add("public_profile");
    strings.add("email");
    loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(contextCallback.getActivity(), strings);
    ArrayList<String> stringss = new ArrayList<>();
    stringss.add("publish_actions");
    loginManager.logInWithPublishPermissions(contextCallback.getActivity(), stringss);
    return this;
}
```

The reason this does not work is that - I think - the login/publish permissions dialog is invoked while the login dialog is still open. This is because the login dialog opens, and then runs asynchronously to your own `authorize()` method, which then tries to open the permissions dialog again.
Obviously, that can fail if the 1st login dialog did not yet complete properly.

Instead, you should wait for the `onSuccess()` callback for the 1st login to complete, and then decide whether you want to open the permissions dialog again to ask for publish permissions.

This is also [documented by Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/permissions#permissions-publish).

Comment: The problems still happens. I don't know what can be. :(

Comment: Try invoking your `publishPermissions()` directly in the `authorizeCallback.onSuccess()` without first making a graph API request. Right now, your code looks very convoluted for something experimental, where you're just trying to get the basics to work.

Comment: You say it stops at [line 53](https://gist.github.com/ppamorim/3cd0a141aac5d52bd60e#file-fail-java-L53). That line reads `DebugUtil.log("PUBLISH PERMISSIONS");`. So I'm guessing your `DebugUtil` is to blame. I recommend that you take a look at the "HelloFacebookSample" app that ships with the Facebook SDK. That app can serve as inspiration to implementing your own app.

Comment: `DebugUtil` isn't blame the source. I mean that `publishPermissions()` is the last method executed. But returns anything.
My login works fine, the problem is with the publish permission...